# Optimality of greedy knapsack algorithm.

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Consider the array of tuples $(t_i, p_i, q_i)$, where $t_i \in \{0, 1\}$ means type of order ($0$ for sell and $1$ for buy), $p_i$ is price of order and $q_i \in (0, 1)$ is volume of the order. Assume we know all $\left[(t_1, p_1, q_1) \ldots (t_n, p_n, q_n)\right]$. We want to construct an algorithm to maximize profit, assuming the following constraints: we can use only deals from the given list and our position (amount of volume we have) is bounded by $1$. Fo example: if we have a sequence of two buy orders with $p = 1$ and $q = 0.5$, and sell order after with $p > 1$, then we receive some positive profit.

My question: obviously, since we have a list of all data, we can start from the end and make a greedy algorithm (buy till possible, then sell with best price and vice versa). But I guess it's not so optimal and the task assumes dynamic programming.

The easiest dynamic possible (I guess) is $d(i)$ is maximum profit based on first $i$ orders. But I unsure about correct dynamic step here. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if I'm understanding this properly. You're buying and selling the same item, but just at differing volumes and prices, and the amount of product you have at any given time must be between $0$ and $1$. Is that right?

Comment: Between $-1$ and $1$. Because we can sell product also (short position) to buy it further with lower price (vice versa scenario).

Comment: I think you can have a dynamic programming solution with two parameters. Instead of $d(i)$, have it be $d(i, v)$, the maximum profit based on first $i$ orders where you must be holding at least $v$ volume after the $i$-th order. You'd then be trying to find $d(n, -1)$. I'm not sure about the time complexity of this though.

Comment: This problem is NP=hard.

Comment: @Apass.Jack sounds like so.